# How to switch off symbol when label is unplaced due to conflicts?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, symbology, maplex

Using either the standard ArcMap labelling engine, or the Maplex engine, it is possible to automatically omit labels from the map when the area is too congested.

Eg in the centre of this image, there are too many towns close together so their labels aren't placed:

[image]

Is there a similar method to switch off those towns' **symbols** as well?

Ideally I'm looking for something automated, which works based on the current viewport (in the same way that the labels are automatically re-positioned if you pan or zoom the map)

Comment: That's an excellent question Stephen, previously I've only been able to do this with feature linked annotation, related tables and definition query. I'd also like to know if there's an automated way of doing it... I suspect it would have to be ArcObjects.

Comment: For OOTB I think you may need to submit an ArcGIS Idea.  If you do, then post a link in an answer and I will happily vote for it.

Comment: Since you are looking for a dynamic solution (work when zooming) I would try this: do _not_ display the circles as _symbols_ of a feature. Use the label engine to display the circles as a _label_. Your label is composed of two parts: the circle and the text.

Comment: Nice idea @Jens - perhaps something like concatenating a string like "+ " using the Python parser for labelling and then getting the offsets and label placements to make sure it falls where the point would.  Worth a try I think.

Comment: @ChrisW good point, I didn't see that post. I agree this should be closed

Comment: @Jens that's a great suggestion - since this post might get closed, you should post your idea to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94446/removing-features-whose-labels-are-not-displayed

Comment: @Stephen Lead - OK, I posted my suggestion as an answer to [Removing features whose labels are not displayed?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94446/removing-features-whose-labels-are-not-displayed/103458#103458).