# How to display features only if labels are displayed?

Tags: qgis, labeling, style

In my maps there are several point layers, and each layer has a different labelling rule and priority. Sometime the point density is too high and the labelling engine is not displaying some labels, following the priority rules I have defined.

Is there a way to display only the points that are labeled? Basically, if there is not space for displaying a label, also the feature should not be displayed.

Comment: Given the nature of the problem, I suspect any solutions or workarounds are going to be similar so you might take a look at the [version of this question asked for ArcGIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94446/removing-features-whose-labels-are-not-displayed?rq=1).